# Regex doesnt replace ' { ' with '<span>{</span>'

Tags: regex, dom

*HTML*

```
<div id = "board_code_dup">
    <div>{abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
   div>ghi}</div>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
var $board_code_dup = $('#board_code_dup');
board_code_dup_html = $board_code_dup.html();

$board_code_dup.html( board_code_dup_html.replace(/{/g, "<span>{</span>") );
$board_code_dup.html( board_code_dup_html.replace(/}/g, "<span>}</span>") );
```

All instance of `}` are replace properly with `<span> } </span>` but **not** for `{`.

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
var $board_code_dup = $('#board_code_dup');
board_code_dup_html = $board_code_dup.html();

$board_code_dup.html( board_code_dup_html.replace(/\{/g, "<span>{</span>").replace(/}/g, "<span>}</span>") );
```

Answer (score 1):

The "{" starts repetition like "{1,3}" and is reserved so you should escape it.

```
$board_code_dup.html( board_code_dup_html.replace(/\{/g, "<span>{</span>") );
```